# Свойства объекта в С++

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть 2 лампочки. У каждой есть 2 состояния - активная(горит) и пассивная(цвет лампочки - черный). В ООП нуб. Создаю для лампочек класс `Lamp` и 2 метода, активирована и деактивирована. Как реализовать для разных объектов этого класса разное значение переменной lampColor?

```
 class Lamp {
    public:
        void activeted(lampColor) {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, lampColor);
            std::cout << "LAMP";
        }
        void deactiveted() {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, blackColor);
            std::cout << "LAMP";
        }
    private:
        HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
        int lampColor;
        int blackColor;

    };
```

Я делал так, но мне кажется это как то не правильно.

```
int redColor = 4;
int greenColor = 2;
Lamp redLamp;
Lamp greenLamp;
redLamp.activeted(redColor);
greenLamp.activeted(greenColor);
```

Можно же как-то более элегантно задавать параметры объектов, а то тавтология получается?

Comment: Не, `blackColor` не надо. Вместо него надо просто хранить состояние -- `bool on`. И при выводе печатать нужный цвет в зависимости от значения `on`

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал следующим образом.

Во-первых, объявил бы перечисление, содержащее допустимые цвета. Потому что такие записи с магическими числами

```
int redColor = 4;
int greenColor = 2;
```

мало понятны.

Для класса я бы определил конструктор, который принимает объект данного перечисления, то есть конструктор изначально задает цвет лампочки. Например,

```
Lamp redLamp( Red );
Lamp greenLamp( Green);
```

где `Red` и `Green` - это определенные в перечислении константы.

Для конструктора можно задать аргумент по умолчанию, который соответствует целому цвету, или каком-нибудь иному цвету. Поэтому если пользователь создаст объект как

```
Lamp whiteLamp;
```

то аргумент можно не указывать.

В самом классе я бы определил два члена данных. Первый задает цвет лампочки, а второй задает состояние лампочки, то есть включена она или нет. Соответственно сделал бы открытыми два метода `switchOff` и `switchOn`, которые меняли бы состояние лампочки и, соответственно, выводили ее на консоль в соответствии с ее состоянием.